# how to populate volley list in fragment?

Tags: android, list, fragment, android-volley

im trying to populate ListView with volley.jar library like this http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/
and its work, but i have no idea to populate that in fragment, can anybody tell me how ? im trying but i have no idea to set adapter from java file to fragment or anything else

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.kue_layout, container, false);
    listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, movieList);
    return rootView;
}
```

`

Comment: Listview.setAdapter(adapter)?

Comment: i need the explanation about how to populate list in fragment ,

Comment: I don't get your problem. You have a listview, you have an adapter, you have your movielist, what is your problem? Why is having a fragment a problem?

Comment: sorry about that, i just need an explanation about how to populate list in fragment, cause i believe it must be different with when i did that in basic activity  . .

Comment: Maybe you should explain why you think it must be different? Or how you did it in your activity and how that doesn't work when it's done in a fragment. It isn't different at all. In your code above you have a reference to a listView and you have an adapter. Now just do listView.setAdapter(adapter) and the listView will use this adapter to display your data.